# Why is Google Chrome blocking raw SWF playback?

Tags: chrome, flash

If you attempt to visit the URL of a raw SWF file, Chrome 57 refuses to display and instead asks if you want to download, with the warning "This type of file can harm your computer". However, if you wrap the same SWF in a simple web page with an object tag, it loads normally. The files are served with the correct "application/x-shockwave-flash" content type.

Is there any security reason why the former case should be treated differently from the latter?

FWIW, I have Flash playback set to "Ask first (recommended)" in chrome://settings/content

Example: http://www.sjgames.com/dice/cthulhudice/demo.html vs http://www.sjgames.com/dice/cthulhudice/img/CDdemo.swf

Comment: Flash is dead,  RIP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is apparently related to how Flash Player is a click-to-enable feature in Chrome now ([Chrome Help forum discussion on this behavior](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BP5jjon7kZA)). If you visit a SWF directly, it will not ask you to click-to-run, it will simply download it instead.

If you were to go to `chrome://plugins/` and check "Always allow to run" it would play the SWF as previously normal in the browser directly, without the HTML wrapper. The fact it will not prompt you to enable it does not seem to be a security decision.

---

> Is there any security reason why the former case should be treated differently from the latter?

All that being said, yes, I think there would be.

Imagine there was a website, say an old forum, which allows you to upload an avatar. It is expected you will upload an image file, but the file type checking is poor, and an attacker uploads a malicious SWF file instead, to perform an XSS attack on the site admins. Now, the HTML being generated for this avatar, might look something like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/user/123/avatar.swf" />
```

That won't run as a SWF, so no HTML for the attacker. So instead the attacker tricks the admins into clicking a link to `http://example.com/user/123/avatar.swf` where the SWF *does* load, and that SWF performs the XSS attack as the privileged users, and PWNs the site.

Of course, such a risk is not unique to Flash Player. A similar attack could be performed with JavaScript inside an SVG instead of a SWF.

Comment: I think he's comparing it to `object` instead of `img src`